# How to add native docker-compose to official Jenkins image

Tags: jenkins, gradle, docker, docker-compose

I am using official Jenkins image:

https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/

I wonder which is the best approach to add native docker-compose to it. For a full continuous integration system I need Jenkins to start Gradle+docker+docker-compose applications but, unlike with Docker plugins,  docker-image plugins for Gradle act just as docker-compose frontend, needing it to be native installed. I will then use simple shell scripts in Jenkins to run the docker-compose up commands before the tests.

Note: Docker should be executed in a external Host, obviously, not locally as we are inside a docker already. I wonder if I can avoid installing the full Docker stack in the Jenkins docker image.

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: You _can_ run Docker in Docker, if that is a concern

Comment: OK, so I should just install Docker and Docker-Compose in the Jenkins image and that's it? Thanks.

Comment: It should work. It probably won't take long to give it a try (not very satisfying I assume :) )

Answer (score -1):

docker-compose is right on the same level as docker-engine - so the host you want to run docker-images / containers on, need `docker-engine`, and if you want to run them using `docker-compose`, you need that on the host - that is best practise